# How to use on the same content box 2 columns of vertical tabs?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I create a new column which is identical to the first column, and have it display one column to the right?

I want the new column to have the same properties as the first column because I want to add more things to this tabs and only on 1 column they are ugly.

Here is what I have tried: http://jsfiddle.net/26zQS/6/

```
<div class="verticalslider" id="textExample">
            <ul class="verticalslider_tabs">
                <li><a href="#">Catedra de Limba si Literatura Romana</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Catedra de Matematica</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Catedra de Informatica</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Limba engleza</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Limba Germana</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="verticalslider_contents">
                <li>
                <h2>Catedra de Limba si Literatura Romana</h2></br>
                <p id="profesor">
                Popa Alina </br>
                Nadia Pascu</br>
                </p>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <h2>Catedra de Matematica</h2></br>
                    <p id="profesor">
                    Ciubotariu Boer-Vlad </br>
                    Diaconu Ilie</br>
                    Gorcea Violin </br>
                    </p>
                </li>

<li>
                <h2>informatica</h2>
                    <p id="profesor">
                    Wainblat Gabriela</br>
                    Nistor Ancuta</br>
                </li>

                <li>
                <h2>Limba Engleza</h2>
                    <p id="profesor">
                    Wainblat Gabriela</br>
                    Nistor Ancuta</br>
                </li>

                <li>
                <h2>Germana</h2>
                    <p id="profesor">
                    Wainblat Gabriela</br>
                    Nistor Ancuta</br>
                </li>

        </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `clone()` function in jquery and `appendTo()`

here is a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/3ru6B/

Comment: what did you try? do you have a fiddle?

Comment: is near my comment de fiddle :))), it is actually after i said does not work

Comment: you want to have another vertical slider tabs next to the original one?

Comment: next to the content box, i want it like in this image ( i made it in photoshop , so everyone will understand )  http://s14.postimage.org/4mi4kx15d/what_i_need.jpg

Comment: @AdiMicutzu its not perfect you are gonna need to play with it

Comment: that is the design, but i want to use every button on different purpose, if i have 10 activities , for example, i want to use every button to describe 10 different activities. In your code the tabs on the right are the same as the first ones ( i mean when you click them they show the same thing )

Comment: ty ^^, srry i do not do something, but i do not know to work in javascript, and i know there is the problem...

Comment: well i will make some retouch, and it will be. Thank you ! :)